# SKSpriteNode only visible on iOS 9 or higher, both in simulator and real phones?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, skspritenode

I noticed this strange error when I tried out my app on my phone. In my game I create a `SKSpriteNode` and then remove it after a couple of seconds. On all iOS 9 devices this works perfectly. But on iOS 8 however, the entire node never appears.

1. I tried if it was the image, but it still happened with just a red coloured SpriteNode.
2. It's not the traditional "red X" error there is just nothing showing up
3. I use the newest version of Xcode: version 8.1 (8B62) and Swift 3.
4. It happens on both the simulator and real phones as long as they are **under** iOS 9
5. It happens on both 32-bit(iPhone 5s) and 64-bit(iPhone 6)

This is all the code related to the node:

```
var forceShield: SKSpriteNode! //outside of the function to make it globally accessable

forceShield = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "forceShield") //SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)) gave the exact same error
forceShield.position = ship.position
forceShield.xScale = 0.4 * scaleFactor
forceShield.yScale = 0.4 * scaleFactor
forceShield.zPosition = 3

let distanceConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 0.0, upperLimit: 0.0), to: ship)
let orientConstraint = SKConstraint.orient(to: ship, offset: SKRange(lowerLimit: 0.0))
forceShield.constraints = [orientConstraint, distanceConstraint]

addChild(forceShield)
```

And to remove it in another function

```
forceShield.removeFromParent()
```

`Scalefactor` is a number which is always bigger or equal to one, to scale the nodes for different devices. `Ship` is another node which is followed by the forceshield (that's what the constraints do).

How can I make this node appear on every device?

Comment: Is this on _all_ iOS 8 devices, or just 32-bit ones?

Comment: Good point, could you elaborate which ones are 32-bit and which are 63-bit? Also, it happened on both an Iphone 5s (iOS 8.3) and an iPhone 6 (iOS 8.3).

Comment: Then it is 64-bit as well and not the known issue I was thinking of that only affected 32-bit devices running 8.0 & 8.1.

Comment: Okay, I will put that in my question as well

Comment: Will it work if you try to remove constraints?

Comment: Yes it did indeed! But however I need the following behaviour, have you got any ideas to fix this and why this is caused?

Comment: I narrowed it down further, it seems to be the distanceConstraint, can you or someone else help me fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by the `distanceConstraint` which wasn't handled correctly in iOS 8 apparently. I fixed this by adding `forceShield` as a subview of `ship` which automatically made it follow `ship` correctly. This solution is of course not always very useful, but it worked for me.